# Spring UserService ClassNotFound using @ViewScoped but works with @SessionScoped

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I have a UserService that fails with ClassNotFound when using ViewScoped but works with SessionScoped and I'm hoping someone can tell me why. My application mixes JSF2 with Spring.

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dave.user.service.IUserService
```

The managed bean is

```
@ManagedBean(name="ClientMB")
@ViewScoped
public class ClientMB implements Serializable{


@ManagedProperty(value="#{UserService}")
IUserService  userService;

public IUserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}

public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

The UserService is defined as

```
public class UserService implements Serializable, IUserService  {

// UserDAO is injected...
IUserDAO userDAO;

}
```

The IUserService is just an interface:

```
public interface IUserService {
```

The declaration in ApplicationContext is

```
<bean id="UserService" class="com.dave.user.service.UserService">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" />
</bean>
```

As I said, this works fine using SessionScoped, but fails when I change the managed bean to ViewScoped.

Comment: this is weird... how your application is being packaged? also, when exactly the error message shows up? on application startup or when you try to access to a page that refers to `#{clientMB}`?

Comment: It is weird! The message shows up when I submit a page that refers to #{clientMB}. The app is still in development with glassfish 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem came from changing the state saving from server to client. Once I returned the state saving to server viewscope worked fine. Not quite sure why that happened but embarassing none the less.